# Trying to setup a Git Server on linux

Tags: git

I am trying to setup a easy git server on linux and I got it working using the following commands

```
git push ssh://git@REGAN/~/mirror.git master
git clone ssh://git@REGAN/~/mirror.git mirror
```

but I am trying to find out why do I have to have the **"ssh://"**

what can I do to make it work without the ssh?

Comment: What alternative do you want to use? HTTP?

Comment: I what it to be like github just git clone git@REGAN/~/mirror.git mirror

Comment: What happens if you just remove `ssh://` from your git command? Which error message do you get?

Comment: fatal: Could not switch to 'git@REGAN/~': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install git-daemon-run
```

Then read the documentation (it's pretty short and clear):

```
less /usr/share/doc/git-daemon-run/README.Debian
```

Then you'll want to create the file `.git/git-daemon-export-ok` in your repo.

More generally, using the ssh protocol is better unless you have a really good reason not to. The git protocol's only advantage is it's somewhat faster, but the speed gains are negligible considering that you lose security by opting out of using the ssh protocol. Using the git daemon, either no one has write access or everyone has anonymous write access. This is usually not ideal.

So, stick to using the ssh protocol. Or if you want to do it right, use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

further useful reading [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html).